# How to make rvalue behave like lvalue reference in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, move-constructor

I am currently writing a simple algebra library in C++. The library has a `Matrix` class defined as follows:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    size_t n, m;
    T **const tab;

public:
    Matrix(const size_t n, const size_t m);
    Matrix(const Matrix&);
    ~Matrix(void);

    RowVector<T> operator[](const int i);
    const RowVector<T> operator[](const int i) const;

    ...
};
```

The code is smart, it not only lets you access some specific element of a matrix (like `M[2][3]`), but it also allows you to use `M[2]` as a vector.

However, as an optimization, the data is not copied to the vector. `Vector` constructed by `operator[]` points to memory inside the `Matrix`. This has to be done, if the `operator[]` call would construct a new vector every time, then accessing one matrix element would be very ineffective.

This also makes it possible to assign matrix elements like this:

```cpp
M[5][7] = 12;
```

However, I have two problems with this solution:

1. Return value of `operator[]` is an rvalue and it's not possible to set a whole row of the matrix like this:

```cpp
Matrix M(2, 3);
RowVector v(3);

M[0] = v;
```

2. When I type something like this:

```cpp
v = M[7];
```

I want `RowVector`'s copy constructor, not move constructor, to be called. But `operator[]`'s return value is an rvalue and the compiler will call the move constructor on it.

In conclusion:

`RowVector` is an rvalue, but it contains a pointer to `Matrix`'s internal data, and I want it to be treated as an lvalue reference.

Is this possible in C++? If not, could someone suggest some refactoring of this code to achieve what I want?

**EDIT:**

`RowVector` declaration:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Vector {
protected:
    const size_t len;
 
    T *const tab;
    bool malloced;
 
public:
    Vector(const size_t len);
    Vector(T *const tab, const size_t len);
    virtual ~Vector(void);
 
    T &operator[](const int i);
    const T &operator[](const int i) const;
};
 
template<typename T>
class RowVector : public Vector<T> {
public:
    RowVector(const size_t len);
    RowVector(T *const tab, const size_t len);
    ~RowVector(void) override;
 
    template<typename U> friend
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&,
                 const RowVector<U>&);
};
```

`Vector` definition:

```cpp
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const size_t len) :
    len(len),
    tab(new T[len]),
    malloced(true)
{
}
 
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(T *const tab, const size_t len) :
    len(len),
    tab(tab),
    malloced(false)
{
}
 
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::~Vector(void)
{
    if (malloced)
        delete tab;
}
 
template<typename T>
T &Vector<T>::operator[](const int i)
{
    return tab[i];
}
 
template<typename T>
const T &Vector<T>::operator[](const int i) const
{
    return tab[i];
}
```

`Matrix<T>::operator[]()`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
RowVector<T> Matrix<T>::operator[](int i)
{
    return RowVector(tab[i], m);
}

template<typename T>
const RowVector<T> Matrix<T>::operator[](int i) const
{
    return RowVector(tab[i], m);
}
```

Comment: This will be hard to answer without seeing the full definition of `RowVector<T>` and a full set of use cases you would like to be possible. Also, why is "calling the move constructor" a problem?

Comment: Your problem isn't that of rvalues and lvalues. You are using one type for more than a single purpose, making it hard to do everything right. I'd split the responsibility. Having a `RowReference` and `RowVector` be seperate types, will allow you to overload in a more refined manner.

Comment: @Botje Here's the definition of the RowVector class: https://pastebin.com/6yYJ8hST . And here declaration: https://pastebin.com/9zXqGBEN

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76128238/edit) instead of linking to third-party sites.

Comment: This is not a [mre]. Where is the definition of `RowVector<T>::operator=`? Where is the definition of `Matrix<T>::operator[]`?

Comment: It looks like you are implementing two sorts of random access iterators. Perhaps what would be a better approach?

Comment: @Botje I added Matrix<T>::operator[] to my question. The move constructor of RowVector is not implemented. I attempted implementing it, and then I came across those issues.

Comment: You could also just `= delete` the move constructor of course. But we cannot help you with "those issues" if we do not know what they are exactly. You also did not show `operator=` which is crucial for both your examples.

Comment: The solution you're looking for is to "Provide a non-const version of the operator[] that returns a reference to a row of the matrix". Its trivial implementation could be tricky because it will assume that the `RowVector` class has a trivial destructor, since the Matrix class is managing the memory for the row vectors and does not call their destructor. If the RowVector class has a non-trivial destructor, you would need to change the implementation to properly manage the memory.

Comment: Since `RowVector` is a class type, you are totally allowed to do `M[0] = v;`.  Have you tried?

Comment: You also can't do `a=b;` where a and b are `Matrix<T>`s since the copy assignment is deleted due to members that are const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I agree with @StoryTeller, this would be best split into a RowVector and RowReference class. However, I'll still go ahead and answer your original question.

Okay, so let's go over this piece by piece.

> 1. Return value of operator[] is an rvalue and it's not possible to set a whole row of the matrix like this:

```
Matrix M(2, 3);
RowVector v(3);

M[0] = v;
```

That's actually not the issue here. It's completely valid to assign to the temporary return value of a function if it's a class type. However, the reason that you're likely running into issues is that you have const members in your RowVector class definition, namely `tab` and `len`. In C++ the default assignment operator `=` is equivalent to saying something like

```
FOR member IN this
    member = other.member
END
```

With this in mind, trying to do `len = other.len` is invalid since len is `const`. For that reason, C++ disables the assignment operator for any classes with `const` members. If you want to define your own assignment operator, you're completely free to do so. I imagine you'd be looking at something like

```
RowVector<T>& operator=(const RowVector<T>& other){
    if (len != other.len)
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot assign rows with different lengths!");
    std::copy(other.tab, other.tab + len, tab);
    return *this
}
```

That should allow you to set an entire row.

> 2. When I type something like this:

```
v = M[7];
```

> I want RowVector's copy constructor, not move constructor, to be called. But operator[]'s return value is an rvalue and the compiler will call the move constructor on it.

I don't believe the move constructor will come into play at all here. Default move constructors are automatically disabled for any class that defines a custom copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, move assignment operator, or destructor. Since RowVector defines a custom destructor, there should be no default move constructor defined and it looks like you didn't define one yourself. This issue probably comes back to the deletion of the assignment operator which would once again be fixed by defining a custom assignment operator.

On a slightly tangential note, storing matrix data as a double pointer `T**` isn't really the most efficient way to create a matrix class. If you're going for efficiency, then you always want to aim for contiguous memory allocation, which in this case would be a `std::vector` of size n x m, and you'd take care of indexing logic in the `operator[]`. Of course, this would also mess up your existing vector classes, so I'll leave it up to you if you want to go that route.